# Why daily catalina.*.log are missing?

Tags: tomcat, logging, catalina

I have been searching myself for a solution, but I could not find anything.

I have tomcat8 with some application deployed on it. During the last weekend, the daily catalina.*.log files have not been created.

Indeed, if I run on command line `ls`, I find this situation:

```
catalina.2017-10-01.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-02.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-03.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-04.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-05.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-06.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-07.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-08.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-09.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-10.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-11.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-12.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-13.log.gz
catalina.2017-10-16.log
```

As you can see, the file `catalina.2017-10-14-log.gz` and `catalina.2017-10-15-log.gz` are missing. As well as, it was missing the file for today, that is `catalina.2017-10-16-log`, but I restarted the tomcat and it has been created.

Checking on the last catalina file before today, `catalina.2017-10-13.log.gz`, the last log is at 17:13:45.081 in which it logs an exception which is catched.. I don't understand what happened. Is there a way to check when and why the tomcat stopped working?

It seems that after that exception tomcat8 went down and only the restart I gave this morning let it start working again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what happened. Is there a way to check when and why the tomcat stopped working?
As you mentioned "Checking on the last catalina file before today, catalina.2017-10-13.log.gz, the last log is at 17:13:45.081 in which it logs an exception which is catched.. " better way to analysis that exception which is catched in the previous logs.

please share the snapshot of that exception.